# Python conditional transform

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, transform

---

```
companies_id     transaction_month     count    
    0                2020-10-01          3
    1                2020-10-01          5
    1                2020-11-01          5
    1                2020-12-01         18
    1                2021-01-01          8
```

> I want the result to be like

```
companies_id      transaction_month     count       first_month
     0                2020-10-01          3           
     1                2020-10-01          5          2020-10-01 
     1                2020-11-01          5          2020-10-01 
     1                2020-12-01         18          2020-10-01 
     1                2021-01-01          8          2020-10-01
```

This is my data set I want to add a new column called "first month" that should contain the value from transaction month column where the corresponding count is >=5.

**for example :**
In case of companies_id 1:

first 5 or more transaction occurred on 2020-10-01 therefore  "first month" column should contain  2020-10-01 throughout i.e to all rows with companies_id as 1.

Comment: And what do you want to do when count < 5?

Comment: please post your dataset as text not as picture/image

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: It should still have the value corresponding to the transaction_month the point is here is I want to identify the first month there was a >=5 transaction and have that value through all the rows corresponding to that companies_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for replace `transaction_month` to `NaN` if not `>=5` count and then use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for first non missing values per groups to new column:

```
df['transaction_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['transaction_month'])

print (df['transaction_month'].where(df['count'] >= 5))
0          NaT
1   2020-10-01
2   2020-11-01
3   2020-12-01
4   2021-01-01
Name: transaction_month, dtype: datetime64[ns]

df['first_month'] = (df['transaction_month'].where(df['count'] >= 5)
                                            .groupby(df['companies_id'])
                                            .transform('first'))

print (df)
   companies_id transaction_month  count first_month
0             0        2020-10-01      3         NaT
1             1        2020-10-01      5  2020-10-01
2             1        2020-11-01      5  2020-10-01
3             1        2020-12-01     18  2020-10-01
4             1        2021-01-01      8  2020-10-01
```